# Configure Spring Batch Job without Meta Tables and Data source for storing real information in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, configuration, spring-batch

No transaction in progress error is shown when cofiguring map job repository with data source for batch writer operation. 
Please help me with my spring batch hibernate configuration.
Here is the log.

```
2018-07-30 03:50:42.415  INFO 8748 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step1]
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
2018-07-30 03:50:43.063 ERROR 8748 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step step1 in job importUserJob

javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(SessionImpl.java:3505) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1427) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1423) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65.flush(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaItemWriter.write(JpaItemWriter.java:84) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:185) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:151) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:284) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:209) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:272) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:66) [spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67) [spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) [spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) [spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:136) [spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:308) [spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:141) [spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:134) [spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:163) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:179) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:134) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:128) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:797) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:781) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.JCG.Application.main(Application.java:10) [main/:na]

2018-07-30 03:50:43.083  INFO 8748 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=importUserJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}] and the following status: [FAILED]
2018-07-30 03:50:43.087  INFO 8748 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5d740a0f: startup date [Mon Jul 30 03:50:36 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-07-30 03:50:43.091  INFO 8748 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2018-07-30 03:50:43.091  INFO 8748 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2018-07-30 03:50:43.095  INFO 8748 --- [       Thread-2] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-07-30 03:50:43.095  INFO 8748 --- [       Thread-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-07-30 03:50:43.111  INFO 8748 --- [       Thread-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am attaching whole sorce code GitHub URL. ( https://github.com/anandvarkeyphilips/Spring-Batch-Hibernate)
Just download or clone and run the repo and you'll get the error. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Manually configuring the `JobRepository` and related beans isn't how you configure those components using the `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotation.  You need to implement your own `BatchConfigurer` in order for those components to take effect.  You can read more about extending the `BatchConfigurer` in the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/job.html#javaConfig